# Events not firing in silverlight custom control

Tags: silverlight

The events in my custom control are just not firing at all.

```
public class MyControl : RadioButton
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);    

        this.Click += (sender, e) => { throw new InvalidOperationException(""); };
        this.Checked += (sender, e) => { throw new InvalidOperationException(""); };
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("");
    }
```

the control loads fine, these events apparently never get fired.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) doesnt look like right signature shouldnt it be protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

Comment: I'm using expression blend, the signature is correct and compiles. Adding the object sender param causes a compilation error. It's also a Silverlight for Windows Embedded 3 project.

Answer (score 0):

Realised what the problem was. I need to declare a template part first and then grab this in the OnApplyTemplate override and hookup the event handler to the 'part'.